# How to manipulate SQL Data

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, qsqlquery

I have set of query like below but the result are not like i want

```
SELECT * INTO #Temp FROM (SELECT Product,PeriodNum,OpenBal,Month Qty,0 as OnHandQty
                      FROM   StockTransaction
                      WHERE Company = 1 AND 
                            FiscalYear = 2016 AND
                            DeptCode = 'phst' and
                            Product = 'Product A' and
                            PeriodNum between 1 and 10) A 

SELECT * INTO #Temp2 FROM (SELECT Product,PeriodNum,OpenBal,Month Qty,OnHandQty
                      FROM   StockTransaction
                      WHERE Company = 1 AND 
                            FiscalYear = 2016 AND
                            DeptCode = 'phst' and
                            Product = 'Product A' and
                            PeriodNum between 1 and 10 and
                            PeriodNum = (SELECT max(PeriodNum) 
                                         from StockTransaction s 
                                         WHERE s.DeptCode =  StockTransaction.DeptCode and 
                                                s.ItemCode = StockTransaction.ItemCode)) C 

SELECT * INTO #Temp3 FROM (C.Product,C.PeriodNum,C.OpenBal,C.Month Qty,C.OnHandQty                               
                       FROM #Temp2 C INNER JOIN 
                            #Temp T ON C.DeptCode = T.DeptCode and 
                                       C.ItemCode = T.ItemCode and 
                                       C.PeriodNum = T.PeriodNum) as  E

SELECT * INTO #Result FROM (SELECT * FROM #Temp
                        UNION ALL SELECT * FROM  #Temp3)  As result

SELECT * FROM #Result
```

[image]

can you help me how to manipulate the data i get???i only data display like picture. If got 5 row of data from select statment, the **OpenBal** value only display for minimum **PeriodNum** and the **OnHandQty** value only display for maximum of **PeriodNum**

Comment: using select **top 3** Product,PeriodNum,OpenBal,Month .........

Comment: why select top 3 @Denny Sutedja?i don't understand, can you explain more?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see an intuitive way to do this on top of my head.

So, assuming you want the data for each of the products, it could go like this.

```
SELECT * INTO #Temp FROM (SELECT Product,PeriodNum,0 as OpenBal,Month Qty,OnHandQty
                      FROM   StockTransaction
                      WHERE Company = 1 AND 
                            FiscalYear = 2016 AND
                            DeptCode = 'phst' and
                            Product = 'Product A' and
                            PeriodNum between 1 and 10 and
                            (Product, PeriodNum) IN (SELECT Product, max(PeriodNum) 
                                         from StockTransaction s group by Product)

SELECT * INTO #Temp2 FROM (SELECT Product,PeriodNum,OpenBal,Month Qty,0 as OnHandQty
                      FROM   StockTransaction
                      WHERE Company = 1 AND 
                            FiscalYear = 2016 AND
                            DeptCode = 'phst' and
                            Product = 'Product A' and
                            PeriodNum between 1 and 10 and
                            (Product, PeriodNum) IN (SELECT Product, min(PeriodNum) 
                                         from StockTransaction s group by Product)

SELECT * INTO #Temp3 FROM (SELECT Product,PeriodNum,0 as OpenBal,Month Qty,0 as OnHandQty
                      FROM   StockTransaction
                      WHERE Company = 1 AND 
                            FiscalYear = 2016 AND
                            DeptCode = 'phst' and
                            Product = 'Product A' and
                            PeriodNum between 1 and 10 and
                            (Product, PeriodNum) NOT IN (SELECT Product, PeriodNum 
                                         from #temp1 UNION SELECT Product, PeriodNum from #temp2)

SELECT * INTO #Result FROM (SELECT * FROM #Temp
                        UNION SELECT * FROM  #Temp2 UNION SELECT * FROM Temp3)  As result

SELECT * FROM #Result
```